# Copy column from Excel to attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, excel

Is there any way to copy a column from excel to an attribute table's column in ArcGIS?

Comment: Is this just to populate a table with data or do these need attached to spatial features?

Comment: Just to populate with data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the purpose is to link data found in an attribute table to and excel file where the spatial information isn't necessary it may be best for you to export the attribute table as a .dbf. You can drag and drop the file into an open excel table (2010 maybe earlier), once the file is open in excel you can do all of your joining within excel and not ArcMap. It seems you may be more knowledgeable with the excel format and this may be the best approach.

Within ArcMap you can import excel files as a table using the Excel to Table Tool. After importing the table you can join the information by using the join field tool. You simply select a field that is common to both the original data and the excel file you are trying to join.

Comment: After I edit the .dbf table in excel it will apear in arcmap with the values I inserted in excel?

Comment: No, it will be a separate file which you can save as an excel table. If you need the information within ArcMap your best bet is to use the Excel to Table tool and then link to the data in ArcMap using the Join Field tool. I would add screen grabs to assist you, but I don't know how to paste them into the comment window.

Comment: I just read that you do not have access to the tool. I would just work outside of ArcMap it seems you have a very limited license. To export the attribute table from ArcMap open the attribute table and select export from the drop down box in the upper left hand corner. Then follow the steps I referenced earlier.

Comment: Thank you. I have arcgis 10.0 i think that tool is only for 10.1 or 10.2

Comment: Let me know if you have had success. Also if your question gets answered don't forget to accept the answer you deem correct.

Comment: I edited the table in excel and made some joins in arcmap with the data I introduced in excel. After the joins I filled the fields I created in attribute table with the data from the joins, then I removed the joins.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that ArcMap data is stored like a database instead of like a spreadsheet and so you need to use the tools ArcMap provides to efficiently get data in/out of it.

There is a pretty thorough guide [here](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0312/importing-data-from-excel-spreadsheets.html) on how to work with excel data in ArcMap.

The actual function you are likely looking for is [Excel to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000055000000)

edit: or try converting your excel to CSV and use [this function](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000027000000).

Comment: Thank you but I still don't know how to do

Comment: How about now? (Added function name)

Comment: The problem is that I don't have that function in Conversion toolbox

Comment: Try my other function using csv?